# Botones dinamicos

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Que tal. Estoy tratando de hace unos botones dinámicos dentro de un modal (el mismo para los tres botones principales). Al momento de dar clic en un botón principal (los de la primer imagen)

[image: Botones principales]

Avivan un modal con más botones, por ahora solo cambia el nombre con un script que coloque pero mi intención es que de igual manera cambie el nombre de los botones y los valores de este.

[image: Modal con botones]

Un ejemplo es que si se da clic al botón de FCH este cambie el nombre de los botones y los valores internos de estos, ya que dentro de cada botón del modal, habrá información diferente para mostrar.

Mi problema o cuestion, es que no se como realizarlo, ya que de `JavaScript` se lo basico. Espero alguien me pueda dar ayuda u orientación. Estoy usando ficheros con format XML para obtener, leer y mostrar la informacion de la base de datos

Comment: Creo que cada botón tendría que tener un atributo que identifique el lenguaje y, al presionarlo, se debe hacer una petición [tag:AJAX] enviando el código del lenguaje para que el controlador devuelva los datos que haya que mostrar en la modal.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Gracias por contestar, a que te refieres con que identifique el lenguaje?

Comment: Por ejemplo: `<button data-lang="es">ESP</button>`. El atributo `data-lang` almacena el código del lenguaje; para los botones ENG este sería `en`, etc. Ese atributo lo envías a tu controlador, este obtiene de tus XML la información de acuerdo al lenguaje, devuelve la información de nuevo al cliente, y finalmente, reemplazas partes de la modal con la información obtenida.

Comment: Me va quedando un poco mas claro, sabras de alguna pagina donde pueda ver un poco de ello?

Comment: Sobre [tag:ASP.NET] y [tag:ajax] no conozco páginas específicas, pero en Google encuentras a montones. En realidad es más fácil de lo que piensas, no te tomará mucho. Esto se simplifica a motones si usas un framework cliente como [tag:vue.js] o [tag:angularjs].

Comment: @GustavoGarcía una pregunta mas... obvio los botones principals, no tienen la misma cantidad de botones en el modal, hay alguna manera de crear botones por medio de un ciclo?

Comment: Por supuesto, con `document.createElement('button')` puedes crearlo, agregarle atributos, cualquier cosa.